# How to redefine `YYSTYPE` in `bison/yacc`?

Tags: yacc

I define a user class to hold all object. But the `yacc` is going to made a header file, which the `yylval`'s type must be `YYSTYPE`. If I do not use `%union`, it will hold it as a int. But if I use `%union`, it will a union. and union is ugly - It cannot hold a class or a shared_ptr (can but not a good idea), It only want me to use pointer.

I just want to make `YYSTYPE` has a type as a user class type. How can I do it?

Comment: I wanna to be going to answer my question...

Comment: If you are using yacc or (more likely) bison with the traditional interface, you will not be able to use an object type which is not trivially copyable. But you won't notice the problem right away: it will show up when the parser needs to resize it's stack, which means it will only happen on inputs which need a lot of parser stack. The resulting bugs can be *very* hard to track down. If you want to do this, use bison and its C++ interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `YYSTYPE`.

With bison -- which is what you are actually using as a yacc implementation-- the correct way to define the semantic value type is

```
%define api.value.type { MyType }
```

If you require that one or more header files be included for the declaration to be valid, put them inside a `%code requires` block:

```
%code requires {
   #include "MyType.h"
}
```

The code generated by these two directives is copied into the header file which bison produces, so other files need only include the generated header file.

**Warning:** Note that unless you use bison's C++ interface, the semantic value type must be trivially copyable, which will eliminate most standard C++ library types. Failing to obey this rule will produce undefined behaviour which may go undetected until you attempt to parse a sufficiently complex input. In other words, tests with simple inputs may not reveal the bug.

Answer (score 0):

As you see, the source file that made by `lex` and `yacc` need the header file that made by `yacc`.

the header is short so we can look for some solution in it.

the part that define the type of `yylval` is this:

```
/* Value type.  */
#if ! defined YYSTYPE && ! defined YYSTYPE_IS_DECLARED
typedef int YYSTYPE;
# define YYSTYPE_IS_TRIVIAL 1
# define YYSTYPE_IS_DECLARED 1
#endif


extern YYSTYPE yylval;
```

so we can define `YYSTYPE` before we include the `yacc`'s header file,  looks like:

```
#include "your-header-file-that-define-the-class.h"
#define YYSTYPE your-class-type
#include "the-header-file-that-made-by-yacc.h"
```